# According to Jehovah's Witnesses is Jehovah God omnipotent, omniscient, and omnipresent?

Tags: nature-of-god, jehovahs-witnesses, omniscience, omnipotence, omniprescence

In talking to Jehovah's Witnesses I found it difficult to discover what they believed on these three attributes:

Omnipotent - God cannot be thwarted by the Devil, sin, sinners, or the world but is all-powerful in all things.

Omniscient - God knows all things about all things, past, present and future, all the time.  Nothing escapes his knowledge, including our thoughts & motives.

Omnipresent - God is in all places, at all times, in the fullness of his being.  It is not just a bit of God everywhere, but *all* of God is everywhere *all the time*.

So he does not need angels or anyone else to inform him of anything anywhere at any time.

What is the Jehovah's Witness belief on these matters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will return later to flesh this out and look forward to your requests for clarification

We don’t teach that Jehovah is omnipresent.

https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/102005167

https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/102011131

We do teach that Jehovah is omniscient.
However when it comes to foreknowledge he does not choose to exercise it in all circumstances.
https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200001549#h=7

We do teach that Jehovah is omnipotent.

https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1953481

Comment: Also, if God could know the future but chooses not to as your view says isn't this a lack of care and love on God's part??

Comment: @AndrewShanks "isn't this a lack of care and love on God's part??" The [illustration](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1200001549#h=18) in the Foreknowledge article Kris posted may help.

Comment: On the other hand If God is not omnipresent, what does it mean to say he is omnipotent?  Does it mean he is omnipotent but only about those things he is aware of?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vh1eCDotdSc&list=PLs7j-0BppWuABuQZeS3eV6IgTGdJhzSSY&index=103

Comment: @Kris - So do you think God has to use one of His special powers in order to be able to see into the future?

Comment: @Kris - Do you not agree that the New Testament does not use the word "foreknowledge" in relation to _socks_ or even _actions_ or _events_ but only in relation to _people_? (Acts 2:23, Romans 8:29-30, Romans 11:2, 1 Peter 1:2).

Comment: @Kris So is it correct to say God only knows what he chooses to know about the future?  You do not agree that God knows the future for the simple reason that He determines the future - "Not a sparrow falls to the ground without your Father's will" Matthew 10:29-31.

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could please add to your answer by giving the JW understanding of Proverbs 15:3, Jeremiah 23:23-24, Acts 15:18, Eph 1:4, Eph 1:11, and 1 Corinth 1:26-31.  Thanks!

Comment: @MikeBorden - thank you Mike.  ("Extremely small" is better.)

Comment: @MikeBorden - I agree, and more, much more.

Answer (score 2):

According to the https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/102005167 article  by the Jehovah's Witnesses God is not omnipresent, but God is omnipotent and omniscient.

> ”The Bible’s Viewpoint

> Is God Everywhere?

> GOD is fittingly described as omnipotent and omniscient​—almighty and all-knowing. Yet, when attempting further to describe God’s greatness, some add a third term​—omnipresent. They believe that God is present everywhere simultaneously.

> While none of these descriptive terms are found in the Bible, the first two are clearly supported by Scriptural teachings. (Genesis 17:1; Hebrews 4:13; Revelation 11:17) God is indeed omnipotent, and he is omniscient in the sense that nothing can be hidden from him. But is he omnipresent? Is God everywhere, or is he a person with a specific dwelling place?"

As can be seen the JW's teach that the terms "omnipotent and omniscient" are clearly supported by Scriptural teachings.